# Combining to statements in a prodedure

Tags: mysql, select, insert, procedure

I am looking to create a procedure with two statements as follows;

```
SELECT isbn, title, author, no, name FROM book, student WHERE isbn='222-3-44-555555-6' AND no='2001';
```

and

```
INSERT INTO loan
VALUES (1013, 2001, '2015.1.20', '2015.1.27');
```

At the moment I have these statements in two separate procedures. Is there a way for me to display the results of the SELECT statement while also inserting the data to the 'loan' table with the INSERT statement in one CALL?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO loan (col1, col2, col3, col4)
SELECT colA,colB,colC,colD
FROM book, student 
WHERE isbn='222-3-44-555555-6' AND no='2001';
```

of course, using the correct column names that you need